# Critical Issues when tracking transaction with Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Google Tag Assistant reports 2 critical errors when tracking an transaction with Universal Analytics:

> Error: Unknown method name: 'addTransaction'
>   Error: Missing 1 required parameter(s) for method 'send'.

The transaction is reported in Google Analytics but I'm worried about this errors. Here's my reporting code:

```
<script>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', {
  'clientId': 'XXX'
});

  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '5',
    'affiliation': 'xxx',
    'revenue': '0', // revenue is 0 because discount coupon was applied
    'shipping': '15',
    'currency': 'CHF'
  });

  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '5',
    'name': 'XXX',
    'sku': '3387',
    'price': '35.80',
    'quantity': '1'
  });

  ga('ecommerce:send');

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

In Google Product Forum user Whims suggests to use

```
ga('send', 'ecommerce');
```

see: http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/L6bWIxPtNbA/PKUJLCfz6qsJ but there's nothing like this in developers docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can ignore the complaints from Google Tag Assistant for now. AFAIK, tag assistant does not know about ecommerce and is throwing up a false positive.

Also, Please do NOT use `ga('send', 'ecommerce');` that whims suggested. It will NOT send the data to GA servers correctly.

I see that this question has been open for quite some time, if the issue was resolved for you and the command `ga('ecommerce:send');` worked for you, Please mark the answer as correct so that people looking at this do not get confused.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction is being reported correctly in Google Analytics, than you should be OK. 
I suspect that Google is still working out bugs between Tag Assistant and Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`)

From looking in the [Google+ Tag Assistant Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/105448214237192581344), it appears that Tag Assistant incorrectly reports an error with `addTransaction` (because it used to be `addTrans` in `ga.js`)